# ZeroClipboard.js onhover cursor pointer issue

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I am using `ZeroClipboard.js`. The cursor pointer *(hover effect)* doesn't come to the copy link at the page load it shows only cursor arrow, only if you interact on page somewhere and go to link again then you see the pointer. Anybody seen this issue, has a solution for fixing it to show pointer on load itself.

Answer (score -1):

With this css:

```
 .zeroclipboard-is-hover { cursor:pointer; }
```

Answer (score -2):

You didn't say what your setup is.
Try with:

```
 var clip = new ZeroClipboard($("#your-copy-button-id"));
 clip.setHandCursor(true);
```

or use css:

```
#your-copy-button-id {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Francesco: it worked for me, and it might work for someone else too. So if you downvoted me, reconsider your vote.

Comment: if it works for you... ok! we must consider zeroclipboard version too